# Group table data with tbody and jQuery.appendTo()

Tags: jquery, html

I am sure that it is just a small issue, but I can't find the root reason why it is not working. I am trying to group data inside a table by using the tbody tag. The tbody tag will be also created by jQuery, but not inserted in the right position.

```
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
    $('<tbody data-set='+key+'>').appendTo('#table__cars');
    $('<tr><td rowspan=3><img class="img--thumbnail" src="'+value.thumbnail+'"></td><td>Model</td><td>'+value.makeModelDescription+'</td><td rowspan=2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td></tr>').appendTo('#table__cars');
    $('<tr><td>Erstzulassung</td><td>'+value.firstRegistration+'</td></tr>').appendTo('#table__cars');
    $('<tr><td>Killometerstand</td><td>'+value.mileage+'</td><td>'+value.isInsideMysqlDb+'</td></tr>').appendTo('#table__cars');
});
```

produces

[image]

But the 15 table rows should be grouped in 5 tbody elements. Can anybody with more experience in jQuery help to find the root cause for the issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Herbert

---

After the suggest change by Parkash Kumar I get the following result. There should be only 3 rows per tbody tag. But now the number of rows decrease from tbody to tbody tag.

[image]

Comment: Can you created a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 1):

With the support of Parkash Kumar I was able to solve the issue by myself. Below a working solution.

```
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
    $('#table__cars').append('<tbody data-set='+key+'></tbody>');
    $('tbody[data-set='+key+']')
        .append('<tr><td rowspan=3><img class="img--thumbnail" src="'+value.thumbnail+'"></td><td>Model</td><td>'+value.makeModelDescription+'</td><td rowspan=2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td></tr>')
        .append('<tr><td>Erstzulassung</td><td>'+value.firstRegistration+'</td></tr>')
        .append('<tr><td>Killometerstand</td><td>'+value.mileage+'</td><td>'+value.isInsideMysqlDb+'</td></tr>');
});
```

Best regards, 
Herbert